# How to get express to listen to external connection?

Tags: node.js, express, podio

I am trying to get this little piece of code working in Node:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var debug = require('debug')('server_auth');
var app = require('../app');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
 debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

it is from the Podio API for node:
https://github.com/podio/podio-js/blob/master/examples/server_auth/bin/www

Point is, I get this going from localhost, and can pick it up, but I have no clue how to get Express respond from an external program.

Answer (score 0):

If you in your firewall have that port, in your case port 3000, open you can use any other computer in your network and make the call against your IP:3000 and then the route you want to reach.